# iOS - BLE state restoration

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using BLE state restoration in my app
The app is connected all night to a peripheral collecting data, and BLE state restoration is meant to revover from crashes. 
In most cases this actually works, but I am seeing more and more failures for testers at home, and when I check the log I see the app was immediately re launched after the crash, but willRestoreState was not called. the result is that seconds after the relaunch I see no more logs from the app, until the user opens it in the morning.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "crash"? Do you simply mean that your app is terminated by the system as usual after a while in the suspended state, or do you actually imply that your app crashes? It matters because CoreBluetooth does specify the behavior on application crashes.

Comment: if I crash my app deliberately (crashlytics.crash) it works. I suspect what is happening to my users is the app is shut down by iOS to release memory. is it expected behaviour that ble restoration re launches my app but does not call willRestoreState ? because this is what seems to be happening